# vb.net reading text between custom tags in text file

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to put settings data values like user/password in one file. I seen it before. I need some assistant to do it in VB.NET

Text file would be formatted like bellow:

```
[TAG] 

 [USERS]
 JOHN DOE,1234,1
 JANE DOE,4321,2

 [COLOR]
 RED,1
 WHITE,2
 BLUE,3

[/TAG]
```

How could I read in between these tags in a text file?

Comment: Fix your post so it is not upper case!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21896/INI-Reader-Writer-Class-for-C-VB-NET-and-VBScript

Comment: Why make up your own format when there are plenty of perfectly good ones out there already, with proper readers and writers?

Comment: I would suggest you use a .xml file. Everything is already built-in .NET to load/paser/save xml information.

Answer (score 0):

My Favorite, aside from writing a custom parser for very easy files, would be to use the [Nini library](http://nini.sourceforge.net/).

In particular, look at [this page](http://nini.sourceforge.net/Manual/NiniManual-2.htm#ASimpleExample) that shows your exact file type.

Hope that helps!